# How to navigate to a new page when user click browser back button

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I am new to javascript, now I have a requirement that i can't finish well. Firstly user in 1.html and then will be navigated to 2.html, then 3.html. Each html has own js file. How To navigate to 1.html when user in 3.html clicking browser back button.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean when the browser back button is pressed? If so, the easiest way would be to use `JQuery`. You can use the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

    $(window).on('popstate', function() {

      var split = location.hash.split("#!/");
      var name = split[1];

      if (name !== '') {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if (hash === '') {
            window.location='www.yourwebsite.com/page1.html';
            return false;
        }
      }
    });

    window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');
  }

});
```

Comment: @XiaominHu Glad to help, don't forget to mark this as the solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Back</button>
```

use this function

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function myFunction() {
    window.location = '3.html'
    }

</script>
```

you can call this function when click button

Comment: sorry, i missed the keyword: its browser back button; Thank you very much for such quick answering my question